# View is not getting displayed after starting a service

Tags: android, service

I am starting a service from activity.The problem here is the service gets started started but the activity is not getting displayed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           startService(new Intent(this, ServerActivity1.class));

        }
```

In the service I am opening a socket via a simple function like this by using a timer.The service gets started as I am able to see in logs but the view(R.layout.main) never gets displayed and after some time the force close pop is displayed.

```
    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "sasa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            read();

        } 
    }, 0,50000);
    Log.i("NoServer","Started1");   
    read();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
     Log.i("Home","Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP+"\n");
}


public  void  read()
{
    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();
   Log.i("Home","Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP+"\n");
               if (SERVERIP != null) {
                Log.i("Home","Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP+"\n");
                }
                try {
                    serverSocket = new         ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                   while (true) {
                      Socket client;
                      Log.i("Home","Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP+"\n");
                    try {
                            client = serverSocket.accept();
                            Log.i("Home","Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP+"\n");
                           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {                                                            
                            serverSocket.close();
                            read();
                        }

                       } catch (Exception e) {

                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
          }
```

Comment: Are you getting ANR while you are reading the socket ?

Comment: ANR means? In the logcat I am not seeing any errors..

Comment: ANR = Applications Not Responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your UI thread (**main**) is being shared by service unless you define your service in a separate process in manifest. If you start your service in activity's **onResume** method, till then your service would be visible but still may cause *ANR* depending on the time (max 5 secs) it takes to complete requests in service.

Its better to put all the socket stuff (or any expensive calls) of your service in a separate **thread**. In that case, your app will not hang or crash due to ANR.

You should use `ThreadHandler` and `Handler` to execute **Messages** and/or **Runnables** in  a separate thread inside Service.

Comment: The problem with handlers is I always want the socket to listen to the port

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

I used the code in the above one.It works perfectly fine but then it won't accept any new messages once a socket connection is made..

Comment: If you dont need to bind your service (in a simple way) with your UI at some times and sending socket data using broadcasts then i would suggest you to set `android:process=":shan"` to your **Service** tag in *AndroidManifest*. By this, your service will run in a separate process (keeping UI thread free) and will allow you to skip threads handler/messages. *Note: I would still suggest you to play with ThreadHandler and Handler stuff*

Comment: It worked perfectly.But still I do have some problems with regard to handlers and threadhandler..